# Draw shadow on iOS - CALayer vs UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, calayer, shadow

What is the best way (in performance and code maintenance) to draw a shadow?

- Have it in the image (png) you want the shadow to be in.
- Draw with CALayer properties

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you would use the UIImage shadow property or pre-render the shadow in the image using a 3rd party tool?

Comment: Second one, i.e., having a .png with the shadow already.